# Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘noscript-marker’

Tags: firefox

I have a relative huge site and each time I refresh it I get this error in firefox 91:

> Content Security Policy: Couldn’t process unknown directive ‘noscript-marker’

I greped the code for 'noscript-marker' but I could not fine any reference.

I commented out all nocript tags but it still brings this warning/error.

can someone give me a hint where I can search?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's not an issue with your code, rather the NoScript extension. You can see your site without the warning if you set NoScript to trusted on that site.